# How to work with hash of hashes in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, struct

I want to build a struct in Perl that has a hash and a variable,then create a hash that each field will contain the struct I created. 
like this:

```
use Class::Struct;

struct exmpl => {hash=>'%' , val => '$'}; 
my %hash_of_structs;
$hash_of_structs { "one" } = exmpl -> new ();
```

Now hash_of_structs has a field with "one" key that contains the struct exmpl.
My question is how do I push new values into the hash that is inside the struct?

I figured how to work with the value in the struct:

```
$hash_of_structs { "one" } -> val ("1");
printf ( "The value is: %d\n",$hash_of_structs { "one" }-> val );
```

But it's not working the same way with the hash in the struct. I tried:

```
$hash_of_structs { "one" } => hash{"uno"}("1");
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you using [Class::Struct](http://p3rl.org/Class::Struct)? It isn't actually a struct; it is just an odd way to create an object. ( Add `Class::Struct::printem(1);` after `use Class::Struct;` to see how your class is actually implemented. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following syntax. If a hash reference is passed, the old content is forgotten, if you supply two arguments, a key - value pair is added.

```
$hash_of_structs{one}->hash({'A', 'a', 'B', 'b'});
$hash_of_structs{one}->hash('key', 'value');
```